# issue in Download file

Tags: android

i have develop applicatin in which i need to download file from url and i have tried following code but i got 0 byte when i shown detail.

**Code::**

```
package com.playmusic;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;


public class playmusic extends Activity {

 private static String fileName = "shanesh.mp3";

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        URL url = new URL("URl");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/download/";
        Log.v("log_tag", "PATH: " + PATH);
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("log_tag", "Error: " + e);
    }
    Log.v("log_tag", "Check: ");
} }
```

**Manifest :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: What is  URL url = new URL("URl"); ????????? Are you specifying http url ??

Comment: ya i have specify http in my url

Comment: then tell me where you got the exception???????

Comment: there are no exception but i got 0 byte file in my sdcard

Comment: have you tried debugging to see if there is any byte passing through the buffer ?

Comment: So there is a file in the downloads-directory which is 0 bytes large?

Comment: Have your tried putting the URL for the file that you want to download in a browser? Does the browser download the file?  Also, you could try  to use a different URL where you for sure know that the file is there and ok...

Comment: @JSydow i got sucess in download mp3 file but not get success in mp4

Comment: @Sephy i got sucess in download mp3 file but not get success in mp4

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 i got sucess in download mp3 file but not get success in mp4 and i have also got success in images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do as follows.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.mysite.com/file.txt");



    try {

        // Execute HTTP Get Request

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();



        printAsString(entity.getContent()));



    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.e(TAG, "There was an IO Stream related error", e);

    }





private void printAsString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String line;



    try {

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            Syso(line);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Error while converting input stream to string");

    }

    is.close();

}
```

Comment: can u tell, wat u want 2 know?.. really i can't understood wat u expecting.. u expecting elaboration on all answers.. try d above n post if u face any prob.

Comment: i got sucess in download mp3 file but not get success in mp4

Answer (score 1):

this is simple code to download any file like image,audio,video etc

```
Button start;
    //String HttpMyUrl="http://am.cdnmob.org/_/img/loader-small.gif";
    String HttpMyUrl="http://ringtones.mob.org/ringtone/RIusrm-7xATkRQlLw1o89w/1424909358/fa1b23bb5e35c8aed96b1a5aba43df3d/stefano_gambarelli_feat_pochill-land_on_mars_v2.mp3";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       start= (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(HttpMyUrl));
                request.setTitle("File Download");
                request.setDescription("File is being Downloaded...");
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(HttpMyUrl,null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(HttpMyUrl));
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);
                DownloadManager manager =(DownloadManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }


        });
```

Give the permission

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to download a file. Try this

```
DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet method = new HttpGet(YOUR URL);
HttpResponse res = http.execute(method);
InputStream responseStream = res.getEntity().getContent();
```

Here I use the GET method and append the parameters to the URL.

Comment: can you give more elaboration

Comment: can you tell me what is difference between my method and your method?

Comment: i have use  `URL url = new URL("url");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();`

Comment: This is just an alternative method. You need to specify a correct url. Something like http://test.com?id=504 or something like that. If you put the url on a browser a file should be downloaded otherwise your url is not correct.

Comment: i got success in download mp3 file but not get success in mp4

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        int count;

    try {
            URL url = new URL("URl");
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();



            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/altered/";
            Log.v("log_tag", "PATH: " + PATH);
            File file = new File(PATH);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
                 }
            File outputFile = new File(file,name);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);


            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                total += count;

                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                fos.write(buffer);

            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error: " + e);
        }
```